# How to find the image of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

I don't how can I find the images,is there any method?

For example,the image of $\varphi(z)=\frac{z-a}{z-b}$ on $[a,b]$ is $[-\infty,b]$.Why?

Or how to find the image of $\omega=\frac{z-3}{z-4}$ over $D=\{z \ |\ 2<2Re(z)<3\}$.

Comment: Are you familiar with mobius transformations?

Comment: @zokomoko Yes I am